# Residuals Checking QQ plot

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

[image]

There are some plots for residuals checking. I am wondering about the QQ plot, since it shows there are some nonnormality in one side of the tail. Based on this, is there hints showing that in which way I may improve the model, or say in which aspect of the data itself has not being deal with properly. which character the data may has?

Comment: If you can figure out what external variable might be causing the Y values that are clustered in the left tail, you might be able to improve the model substantially.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Thanks for the hints! when you say external variable, you mean the variable that I didn't include in my model?